# React.js import statement cannot find module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am build an Configurable Tab in React.js. I pass the all tab into to the Tab component and build the tabs and the tab content. I use the `import(`${path}`)` to load the component in the tabs dynamically.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const path = '../Clock.tsx';
    const loadComponent = async (index) => {
      const componentModule = await import(`${path}`);
      setComponent(() => componentModule.default);
    };
    loadComponent(activeTab);

  }, [activeTab,props.tabs]);
```

the above code gives me error 'Error: Cannot find module '../Clock.tsx'.
If i change the import code to `import('../Clock.tsx');` it works.

What am i doing wrong.
Git Code for reference: https://github.com/HimanshuK18/react-app/commit/90527c836ab1298b09550bcbb3d8aa41a5c1e843

**Similar code in this file works.**
https://github.com/HimanshuK18/react-app/blob/8de716a407d0d2605a4f455e039519099fbdcf35/src/projects/Tab/DynamicImport.jsx

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at Webpack's [Dynamic expressions in import()](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#dynamic-expressions-in-import):

> It is not possible to use a fully dynamic import statement, such as import(foo). Because foo could potentially be any path to any file in your system or project.
>
> The import() must contain at least some information about where the module is located.

When you import like this:

```
await import(`${path}`);
```

It renders to this, which is not possible:

```
await import(path);
```

You run into this problem because your dynamic import contains no direct information about where the Clock component path is. You have the path information inside the `path` variable (`../`), however, that should be moved to within the `import` function itself.

A simple solution is to use the following:

```
const path = 'Clock';
...
const componentModule = await import(`../${path}`);
```

Here's an [example sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react18-2-typescript-dynamic-imports-91jjmc) showing this behavior. Here is a [discussion](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6680#issuecomment-370800037) on the issue as well.

Answer (score -1):

I think the issue is about the name of variable.

Please try to use this:

```
const componentModule = await import(path);
```

If you pass `path` as an variable into template string, it will consider the variable content includes the single quotes, which makes the error happened.

Comment: It's not correct. This would be true if he wrote the apostrophes within the backticks inside the import(). (`await import("'../Clock'");`) but in this case it simply renders to a string. I used quotations here as an example but the same is true for backticks.